# Skipping over row if it doesn't exist. MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, row

I'm making a personal website.
I'm stuck on the blog. I have it so it shows 5 per page, and it's fine when there are no breaks in the ids in my MySQL table.
But, I have the ability to delete blogs, and that messes everything up, because my loop includes the missing id, and shows nothing, so there is only 3, or 4 per page.
[image]

(the blog with id=10 was deleted)

I'm not going to show all the code, but here's some.

```
$i = $blog_count-(($currentpage*$maxperpage)-$maxperpage);
while ($i >$blog_count-(($currentpage*$maxperpage)-$maxperpage)-$maxperpage){
//render the blogs
$i--;
}
```

$blog_count is equal to how many rows are in the table.
I have another variable that I was messing around with, which is $maxid. It's simply the largest id number.

Any help would be appreciated. I have a feeling I should know how to do this, but I'm stumped.

EDIT: I changed my code to

```
$start = $currentpage*$maxperpage-$maxperpage;
$query = "SELECT * FROM blogs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start,$maxperpage";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while ($blog = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

And it works.

Comment: what is your SQL query to retrive the blog articles currently? The work you are doing in PHP (also the work to skip inexisting rows) can certainly be done in your SQL query

Comment: do you know about the `limit` clause in MySQL?

Comment: The code you've posted just seems like overkill! :s

Comment: Wow, quick responses! 
The query to retrieve the blog articles is
`$query  = "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE id = ".$i."";`
And no, I don't. I just started learning PHP and MySQL a couple days ago. 
And craig, I know lol, but it's the only way that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be that you are not using your database properly.

You should let the database return a collection of rows filtered and sorted according to your needs. In a typical blog scenario (where articles might be inactive/not-yet-made-public) you would ask the database to return a collection of active articles sorted by date. Read up on basic SQL and do yourself a favor and use a decent ORM (a database abstraction layer making it easy to perform queries, isolating you from raw SQL).

As has already been mentioned, you can use LIMIT to get a subset of rows in case you want to do pagination.

Comment: I was thinking about sorting by date, but i just thought sorting by id would be easier, or the same. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Ok 2 things I would suggest...

Using the MySQL limit clause, which will limit the amount of results returned.

I.e

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` LIMIT 10;
```

Or use another field like `deleted` to determine if the row is "deleted", so itll still be in the database, but not active.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you shouldn't be relying on the arbitrary id field of the blog post.  Pull your posts in sorted order from the database and then output them in a loop.  Here's some example code to help you get started:

```
$results = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Posts LIMIT 5, 5 ORDER BY id DESC");
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
//Pull data from the row and display it
}
```

So, this code will pull the 6th to 10th posts from the database, regardless of what posts have been deleted.  The first parameter for LIMIT is the number of rows to skip (so, 0 for the first page, 5 for the second, etc) and the second parameter is the maximum number of results (you want this to always be 5).